# Bind jquery slider to fade between 3 images?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a jquery slider that will allow for fading between 3 images?

The end effect i'm trying to create is taking 3 of the same images, one that is clear, one that has some blur applied to it, and one that has some blur applied to a different area of the image. Using values of 0-200 on the slider, as the user drags the slider from 0-100 it would fade between image 1 and 2. As the user drags slider from 101-200 it would fade between images 2-3.

I've got something put together working out just a fade between the first two images, but i think i am going about this completely the wrong way.

Simple HTML:

```
<div id="fader1">
    <img src="http://egegorgulu.com/assets/img/beforeafter/after.jpg">
    <img src="http://egegorgulu.com/assets/img/beforeafter/before.jpg">
    <img src="http://egegorgulu.com/assets/img/beforeafter/after.jpg">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#slider").slider({
   value:100,
   min: 0,
   max: 100,
   slide: function( event, ui ) {
       $( "#slider-value" ).html( ui.value );
       fader2.setPanelOpacity(0,ui.value / 100 );
       }
   });

Fader.prototype.setPanelOpacity = function(index, opacity){
  if (isNaN(opacity)) opacity = 0;
  opacity = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, opacity));
  this.panels[index].opacity = opacity;
  if (this.useOpacity){
    this.panels[index].node.style.opacity = opacity;
  }else{
    this.panels[index].node.style.filter  =
        'alpha(opacity=' + (100 * opacity) + ')';
  }
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m0qrapk9/3/

Comment: Please include all relevant HTML, CSS, and JavaScript in the question here on Stack Overflow, not only on an external site, as a [mre]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to allow people to run the code here on SO.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my original post